# jQuery Hover event is not bound to the child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I bind the hover event to the `li` tag(see my code below or fiddle, for code details), i.e. when i hover over the `li`, i added the class which changes the background of the `li`.

`li` tag is having one `a` tag which encloses two `span` tags with texts, when i hover over the two text `span` tags, i am not seeing the hover event is executed. Please see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/JbVMv/ . Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
     <title>Untitled Page</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css"></link>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/mystyle.css"></link>

     <script src="/jquery-my.js" ></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var groupTab = $("ul").children("li");  
            groupTab.hover(function(){
            if(!($(this).children("a").hasClass("current")))
            {
                $(this).siblings("li").children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");            
                $(this).children("a").addClass("hoverBG");
            }                   
            });         
            groupTab.mouseout(function(){
                $(this).children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");               
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        li{background-color:#DCDEDB;
            border:1px solid black;
            padding:20px;
        }
        .hoverBG{
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="">
            <ul class="" id="">

                   <li class=" ">
                        <a class="current" href="#" >
                            <span class="">
                                MyName
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="">MyData</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                   <li class="" >
                        <a class="" href="#" >
                            <span class="">
                                MyName
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="">MyData</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                   <li class="" >
                        <a class="" href="#">
                            <span class="">
                                MyName
                            </span>
                            <br>
                            <span class="">MyData</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>

 </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) jQuery function takes two arguments, the function to be executed at `hover` (mouseenter) and the function to be executed at `hover out` (mouseleave). You should use that instead of `mouseleave`

```
groupTab.hover(function () {
        if (!($(this).children("a").hasClass("current"))) {
            $(this).siblings("li").children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");
            $(this).children("a").addClass("hoverBG");
        }
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/JbVMv/4/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use mouseenter and mouseleave events instead mouseover and mouseout

I edited your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JbVMv/1/

```
jQuery(function($){
            var groupTab = $("ul").children("li");  
            groupTab.mouseenter(function(){
            if(!($(this).children("a").hasClass("current")))
            {
                $(this).siblings("li").children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");            
                $(this).children("a").addClass("hoverBG");
            }                   
            });         
            groupTab.mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");               
            });
        });
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handler hover state in the children then you need to use the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events.

The shortcut for using both these events is too use the [.focus(fn1, fn2)](http://api.jquery.com/focus/), where fn1 is the mouseenter callback and fn2 is the mouseleave callback

```
jQuery(function($){
    var groupTab = $("ul").children("li");  
    groupTab.hover(function(){
        if(!($(this).children("a").hasClass("current")))
        {
            $(this).siblings("li").children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");            
            $(this).children("a").addClass("hoverBG");
        }                   
    },function(){
        $(this).children("a").removeClass("hoverBG");               
    });         
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eADCL/)

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your code to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

http://jsfiddle.net/mchail/uVsEQ/1/

This example should work as you intended. The main thing to learn is that `mouseout` will fire for an element when you mouse over one of its **child** elements.

Read more about event propagation and the difference between `mouseout` and `mouseleave` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/mouseout

Answer (score 1):

We can use mouseover and mouseout function, follow below example:
//HTML

```
<div class="">
<ul class="" id="">
    <li class=" ">
        <a class="current" href="#" >
            <span class="">MyName</span>
            <br>
            <span class="">MyData</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="" >
        <a class="" href="#" >
            <span class="">MyName</span>
            <br>
            <span class="">MyData</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="" >
        <a class="" href="#">
            <span class="">MyName</span>
            <br>
            <span class="">MyData</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
li{
    background-color:#DCDEDB;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:20px;
}
.hoverBG{
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

//JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("ul").children("li").each(function() {    
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find('a').addClass('hoverBG');
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find('a').removeClass('hoverBG');
        });
    });
});
```