# JQuery drop down menu mouse hover. Menu closes

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

on the site http://va.in-design.com when I hover over the menu everything works fine. However, when I try to get to the submenu links and children, the menu closes. I think this might have to do with having a transparent background. If there any way to not make it close.

Thanks,
Tamer Z

Comment: Can you add your js, css and html on a jsFiddle?

Comment: I tried adding the parts to JSFiddle but could not get it to function. Not sure what all I have to do. I will try again and let you know when I do it. Thanks,

Comment: I added it. Please check out: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tziady/XFqAd/
It works perfectly on JSFiddle. My assumption is that some other layer is messing with it. I have some mouseenter events that don't work on the text tags either. Wonder if it is the html or body cs code. Trying to remove it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the submenu is not a child of the menu.  So when you are hovering over the submenu, you are no longer hovering over the menu, and it closes.  You can restructure your code so that the submenu is a child of the top level menu item.

Comment: Ok, I am very very new to CSS. I will look through the code to see what you mean? Can you give me a pointer on how to make it a child of the top menu? Is there an easy way or do I have to restructure allot? Thanks for the pointer. Will post back with what I can figure out.

Comment: can you give me a little clue on how to actually do this. Is this in the CSS or the HTML. I am sorry; but I am not sure how the child inheritance is or is not gained.

Comment: I'm sorry, looking at it more closely, I think something else is going on there.  Not sure what, right now - I'll try to take a look for a few minutes.

Comment: I think it is something in your CSS, because it seems to work if all the CSS is removed.  Try removing it all and then slowly adding it back and see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you bind the mouse events on the LI, which should include all children, but don't. Have you tried changing your structure to:

```
<DIV align="center">
<ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">
<DIV class="someclass">
<LI>
```

...then bind mouse events to ("#someclass") instead of "#sdt_menu > li"?

When you bind the mouse event to the LI, it's obviously not also attaching to the child DIV, although does attach to the child A elements.

---

Another possible answer is [to use `.hover` instead of `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099196/2683954).

> The [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) jQuery function takes two arguments, the function to be executed at `hover` (mouseenter) and the function to be executed at `hover out` (mouseleave). You should use that instead of `mouseleave`